# PHP and PayPal IPN array

Tags: php, arrays, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am getting PayPal's IPN in array form like this:

```
$ipn = array(
    'mc_gross' => '15.50',
    'protection_eligibility' => 'Eligible',
    'address_status' => 'confirmed',
    'item_number1' => '1',
    'tax' => '0.00',
    'item_number2' => '2',
    'payer_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'address_street' => '1 Main St',
    'payment_date' => '02:41:18 Nov 23, 2011 PST',
    'payment_status' => 'Completed',
    'charset' => 'windows-1252',
    'address_zip' => '95131',
    'mc_shipping' => '0.00',
    'mc_handling' => '0.00',
    'first_name' => 'Test',
    'mc_fee' => '0.75',
    'address_country_code' => 'US',
    'address_name' => 'Test User',
    'custom' => '',
    'payer_status' => 'verified',
    'business' => 'receiver@example.com',
    'address_country' => 'United States',
    'num_cart_items' => '2',
    'mc_handling1' => '0.00',
    'mc_handling2' => '0.00',
    'address_city' => 'San Jose',
    'payer_email' => 'payer@example.com',
    'mc_shipping1' => '0.00',
    'mc_shipping2' => '0.00',
    'txn_id' => '8RE82733S8684874F',
    'payment_type' => 'instant',
    'last_name' => 'User',
    'address_state' => 'CA',
    'item_name1' => 'trilogy2',
    'receiver_email' => 'receiver@example.com',
    'item_name2' => 'trilogy1',
    'payment_fee' => '0.75',
    'quantity1' => '1',
    'quantity2' => '1',
    'receiver_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'txn_type' => 'cart',
    'mc_gross_1' => '5.55',
    'mc_currency' => 'USD',
    'mc_gross_2' => '9.95',
    'residence_country' => 'US',
    'transaction_subject' => 'Shopping Carttrilogy2trilogy1',
    'payment_gross' => '15.50',
    '' => ''
    );
```

In this case customer has ordered only 2 items: `'item_name1'` and `'item_name2'`

Obviously, a customer can order X number of products and PayPal will include an `'item_nameX'` in the notification data. Is there a way to go through the array and extract all names and assign them to variables so I will have something like:

```
$ordered_item1 = $ipn['item_name1'];
$ordered_item2 = $ipn['item_name2'];
...
$ordered_itemXYZ = $ipn['item_nameXYZ'];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a way you can create a basket on your side, pass over a reference to paypal that relates to this users basket (session_id maybe) and do your additional logic (maybe mark it as a valid order, send email, etc) once paypal has either confirmed or declined?

Comment: No, because I'm using different server for shopcart and different one for checkout (it's complicated to explain, and not relevant for this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data named with a prefix followed by a count, you should be using an array, not separate variables. To fill an array with the item information:

```
foreach ($ipn as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/(?P<field>[a-z]+)_?(?P<i>\d+)/', $key, $parts)) {
        $ordered_items[(int) $parts['i']][$parts['field']] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates multidimensional array with some additional fields (quantity, gross). Is there a way just to strip down that to "name only" ?  ...sorry for bugging, but I really don't get the arrays at all :(  Thanks !